# How to Register/Link to .js Files in WordPress Dynamicaly in Header.php

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

Can you please let me know how I can dynamically register/link to my js files in wordpress?
I have two js files as below code but I do not know how to map to them uring the `bloginfo()` as it is taking parameters!

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your assets folder inside your custom theme or a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

We can use wp_enqueue_scripts action to hook js.

If it is inside theme folder then,

```
<?php

    function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>
// If it's for plugin,If it's for plugin, 
//use plugins_url( '/js/newscript.js' , __FILE__ )  as path.
```

For ref [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score 0):

I´m using this code   script src="?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/html5/html5shiv-printshiv.js">  
 you only need to add the line bloginfo('template_directory') to your code to header.php 
 
 `script src="?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/html5shiv.js">`
 I had to avoid some "<" in order to place the code. 
As the code describes template directory all your JS files should be on the folders /assets/js/ within the folder template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your custom js code then what you have to do is first register your custom script then enqueue it.

**Example**

```
function link_my_js()
{
 wp_register_script('desired_name',_template_directory().'/assets/js/custom-script.js');
 //now enqueue it
 wp_enqueue_script('desired_name');
//desired_name(called handle) is what you have given in wp_register_script above
}
```

now add this in a action hook

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','link_my_js');
```

Place the codes in functions.php

If you want to use this in plugin give correct path on registering the script use `plugins_url()` to get the directory path then continue with yours and use it inside the plugin.

If you want to link general main jquery just use the handle name `jquery` alone you don't have to register it, because WordPress provides preloaded scripts in the core you can check it [Here Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) at the bottom. Feel free to ask doubts on this:)